# Receiving an error when trying to run pub

Tags: flutter, dart

In VSCode and trying to run the following:

```
dart pub upgrade
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory
```

However, my flutter file seems fine. Flutter Doctor output below:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Any idea how I can resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: did you need to upgrade your dependency

Comment: @MrShakila I get this whenever trying to use any Pub commands but not sure what is causing this

Comment: if you're using some proxies that may cause the issue

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with proxies, but anyway I should resolve?

Comment: flutter pub upgrade --major-versions try this for flutter

Comment: Getting the error: Could not find an option named "major-version".

Comment: flutter pub upgrade try this

Answer (score 1):

first clean dart using `dart pub cache clean`

then run `dart pub get`

After that run `dart pub get upgrade`

Comment: anytime I run a dart pub command I get: "Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory"

Comment: Any idea how I can re-install this or if address pointing to the right SDK

Comment: did you install dart SDK two times?I found this question if you did so

Comment: I dont think so but is there a way to check?

Comment: Is there a way to delete all potential versions of dart and redownload it?

Comment: I m not sure that dart can be deleted without flutter ,  I think deleting complete flutter and reinstalling maybe works

Answer (score 0):

try creating a .bashrc file in your user's folder.

Then add the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dart/installation/bin/folder
export PATH
```

Comment: Still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have installed Dart-sdk two times. One time as a windows installer, and the other through chocolatey for instance. Uninstall the one you have in "Add/Remove programs", or at least make sure you only have one, and it should work.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this on mac?

Comment: Refer here -> https://dart.dev/get-dart